# Tool for .net Assembly Encryption

Tags: .net, encryption

What are some good tools for .net Assembly Encryption?

I know of [codeveil](http://www.codeveil.com/) and [CodeWall](http://www.codewall.net/)

I played around with both but was wanting to know

1. are there other/better tools out there
2. plus/minuses and experience with these two tools.

Please no debate on obfuscation, encryption and all that. I have been asked to make a .net app be written out to unmanaged code and encrypted. If there are some good papers, articles, or research on the effectiveness or use of assembly encryption that would be great.

Answer (score 0):

I have used [{smartassembly}](http://smartassembly.com/) for a few years now. It was really easy to automate via integration into our MSBuild process. When deciding which tool to use we tested all the popular obfuscation tools available at the time and found {smartassembly} worked for all our test cases. I suggest performing trials of the tools yourself then attempt to decompile to see what you get.

Comment: smartassembly is an obfuscator,right (I could be wrong)? 
I am looking for something that makes the code unmanaged code and encrypts the assembly.